# Using http_get php

Tags: php, http, get

While using a certain API to extract information the docs suggest that I need to pass a URL to retrieve data. The data is returned in `XML`, however to receive it in `JSON` format HTTP Accept header value of `'application/json'` should be specified.

I am trying to achieve this in PHP, e.g. the URL to retrieve information is `http://www.example.com?someContent` which returns data in XML.

I am currently using [`http_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php) function from PHP, however, it doesn't seem to be working at all.

Any suggestions on how can I extract information and then also request it in `JSON` format.

The above link is invalid.  This documentation exists at [`http_get`](https://php.uz/manual/en/book.http.php)

Comment: Are you sure you installed the http pecl extension? (the `http_get` method comes in that package) http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

Comment: @pozs, I am not sure as I am directly using it from MAMP

Comment: Then, you are not. It won't work without it. Follow the instructions from the page above i linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but this should work.  Set the headers option to an array of headers you want to use.

```
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/?someContent", array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  )
), $info);

print_r($info);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to work at all (stops page from loading anything), probably some syntax error I think, but I can't find any.

Comment: Should `'Accept': 'application/json'` be `'Content-type: application/json'` instead?

Comment: @Namit, No, `Content-Type` is a response header.  `Accept` is the request header telling the server what content types you will accept.  Turn on your error log to see what's going on.  Your server may not allow a connection to the outside.

Comment: This is what it says: parse error, expecting ')'' on the line with `'Accept' : ...`

Comment: Oops, sorry, wrong language.  `:` should be `=>` instead.  Fixed.

Comment: Link is dead. Wayback copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20160101042724/http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$body = http_parse_message(http_get($url))->body;` then you can use `$body`.

Alternatively, you can use cURL. Since the result is in JSON, you'll need to parse the XML then output as an array into the `json_encode` function.